# How can you make this a script?

Tags: powershell, scripting

how can these commands be in a PS script ? I'm working with PC hardware and the basics like installing Windows and Office systems, but I get a lot of PC's to reinstall Windows and sometimes the Windows Updates just get stuck on searching for updates, the only way that worked for me was these commands. Can this be automated with 0 user interaction ?

```
set-executionpolicy remotesigned

Install-Module PSWindowsUpdate

Import-Module PSWindowsUpdate

Get-WindowsUpdate

Install-WindowsUpdate
```

Comment: what's wrong with just saving what you wrote as a script? I mean, you'll have to add like `-force -confirm:$false` or something like that to the `Install-Module` cmdlet so that it doesn't prompt with the "Are you sure you want to install this module?" garbage, but the rest of that should just work as intended I think.

Comment: It does not make any sense to have `Set-ExecutionPolicy` in a PowerShell script. ;-) That's like the chicken and egg problem. Regardless of that - do you really want to install the module every time you run this script? That schould only be necessary once for each computer you're running this script on. ;-)

Comment: This is a good start. Think what can go wrong based on your experience with running these commands manually. Then handle each of these situations. For example, what happens when the workstation is out of disk space? or it can't connect to the network? The more fringe scenarios you automate the less manual intervention will be needed.